# Issue with an istream friend function in a class receiving input

Tags: c++, class, friend, ostream, istream

I have a class for working with rational numbers with three files and my goal is to be able to satisfy this output

```
correct output:
Enter operator (+,-,*,/,==,>=,<=,!=,<,>,-1 for negation): -
Enter the two operands (ex. 1/2 or -3/4): 2/3 3/8
(2/3)-(3/8)=7/24
```

Everything works fine except a runtime error where the second rational for some reasons defaults to 0/1, which I think means the second number isn't being accepted.

```
my output:
Enter operator (+,-,*,/,==,>=,<=,!=,<,>,-1 for negation): +
Enter the two operands (ex. 1/2 or -3/4): 2/3 3/8
(2/3)+(0/1)= 2/3
```

Any help is appreciated!

```
RATIONAL.h

friend istream& operator >> (istream& ins, Rational &r);

RATIONAL.cpp

istream& operator >> (istream& ins, Rational &r)
{
    bool isnegative = false, slashfound = false, isvalid = true;
    string str;
    ins >> str;
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < str.length(); i++)
    {
        if(str[i] == '-')
        {
            if (i != 0)
                isvalid = false;
            else 
                isnegative = true;
        }
        else if(str[i] == '/')
        {
            if(i = 0 || (i == str.length()-1) || (isnegative && i == 1) || slashfound)
                isvalid = false;
            else
                slashfound = true;
        }
        else if(!isdigit(str[i]))
            isvalid = false;

        if(!isvalid)
        {
            ins.setstate(ios::failbit);
            return ins;
        }

        istringstream istr(str);  

        if (slashfound)
        {
            int n, d;
            char c;
            istr >> n >> c >> d;
                if(d == 0)
                {
                    ins.setstate(ios::failbit);
                }
                else
                {
                    r.numerator = n;
                    //r.denominator = 1;  // slashfound
                    r.denominator = d;
                }
        }
        else // case where slash not found
        {
            istr >> r.numerator;
            r.denominator = 1;
        }

    }
    return ins;
}

MAIN.cpp
cout << "Enter the two operands: ";
cin >> r1 >> r2;
```

picture for convenience and assume all header files are in code etc
[image]

Comment: And when you ran your code in a debugger, what observations did you make? This is a good opportunity to learn how to use it to run your programs one line at a time, inspect all variables and their values as they change, and analyze your programs' logical execution flow. Knowing how to use a debugger is a required skill for every C++ developer, no exceptions. With your debugger's help you should be able to quickly find the bug in this and all future programs you write, without having to ask anyone for help.

Comment: unfortunately, I am not familiar with using debuggers and I tend to debug things simply by commenting out code and running one function at a time. I do plan on get familiar with one eventually.

Comment: The sooner you "get familiar" with one, the sooner you will be able to find bugs in your own code, without having to ask anyone else for help.